# Grep lines that end with numbers

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a list of lines like:

```
Spend: 4,100
Spend2: 2,200
Spend3: 300
Spend4: 1,590
Spend5:
```

and I'm trying to `grep` just the lines that end with numbers

I tried

```
grep "[0-9]+$" filename.txt > filtered.txt
grep "\d$" filename.txt > filtered.txt
```

but none of these worked

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 5):

The `+` operator is not supported by traditional `grep`, whose regular expression repertoire is very limited.

All you really care about is whether the last character is a digit, so

```
grep '[0-9]$' filename.txt
```

should do what you want. Other approaches include

```
grep -E '[0-9]+$' filename.txt   # use extended regex repertoire
grep '[0-9]\+$' filename.txt    # POSIX BRE extended
grep -P '\d+$' filename.txt    # PCRE extended; not portable
```

Notice how I use single quotes throughout. Double quotes introduce additional complications especially with backslashes which you probably want to avoid.

Comment: How do the `+` signs in the last 3 examples help, please? Surely a line ending in `7` ends in a number regardless of how many digits precede it? And if it doesn’t end in a digit, it won’t match even if you omit the `+`?

Comment: Sure, I just want to cover the OP's error in more detail in case they also have scenarios where the `+` is properly required, or at least useful.

Answer (score 0):

On *Basic regular expressions* mode you should specify the pattern in the following way:

```
grep '[0-9]\+$' filename.txt > filtered.txt
```

---

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ‘`?`’, ‘`+`’, ‘`{`’, ‘`|`’,
>   ‘`(`’, and ‘`)`’ lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed
>   versions ‘`\?`’, ‘`\+`’, ‘`\{`’, ‘`\|`’, ‘`\(`’, and ‘`\)`’.

Comment: I don't get any result

Comment: @DavidHalliday, if you don't get any result - then, you made an error

Answer (score 0):

For extended regular expressions you should use `egrep` or `grep -E`.